# Tensorflow: pattern training and generation

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Imagine I have hundreds of rectangular patterns that look like the following:

```
_yx_0zzyxx
_0__yz_0y_
x0_0x000yx
_y__x000zx
zyyzx_z_0y
```

Say the only variables for the different patterns are dimension (width by height in characters) and values at a given cell within the rectangle with possible characters `_ y x z 0`. So another pattern might look like this:

```
yx0x_x
xz_x0_
_yy0x_
zyy0__
```

and another like this:

```
xx0z00yy_z0x000
zzx_0000_xzzyxx
_yxy0y__yx0yy_z
_xz0z__0_y_xz0z
y__x0_0_y__x000
xz_x0_z0z__0_x0
```

These simplified examples were randomly generated, but imagine there is a deeper structure and relation between dimensions and layout of characters.

I want to train on this dataset in an unsupervised fashion (no labels) in order to generate similar output. Assuming I have created my dataset appropriately with [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) and [categorical identity columns](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/feature_columns):

- what is a good general purpose model for unsupervised training (no labels)?
- is there a Tensorflow premade estimator that would represent such a model well enough?
- once I've trained the model, what is a general approach to using it for generation of patterns based on what it has learned? I have in mind [Google Magenta](https://ai.google/research/teams/brain/magenta), which can be used to train on a dataset of musical melodies in order to generate similar ones from a kind of seed/primer melody

I'm not looking for a full implementation (that's the fun part!), just some suggested tutorials and next steps to follow. Thanks!